# how do I use powermockito verifyNew?

Tags: powermock

Having trouble with this. I've used Powermockito quite a bit in the past. Normally this is pretty smooth. I figured I'd post my problem rather than continue to rummage through examples. So the goal is to verify a call to new for a class. I don't think this is the most popular feature of powermockito. 
Here's the test:

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyNew;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class VerifyNewTest {

  ClassUnderTest myClassUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    whenNew(Collaborator.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(new Collaborator());
    myClassUnderTest.doSomething();
    verifyNew(Collaborator.class).withNoArguments();
  }

}
```

and said classes

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

  public void doSomething() {
    new Collaborator();
  }
}


public class Collaborator {

}
```

My goal was to make this as simple as possible. I suppose I could have added some mock objects and stubbed some behavior. Anyway, I get.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:  Unfinished stubbing detected here:
    -> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocationcontrol. MockitoNewInvocationControl.expectSubstitutionLogic(MockitoNewInvocationControl.java:65)
```

E.g. `thenReturn()` may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:

```
when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Hints:
 1. missing `thenReturn()`
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!

Comment: right before I hit post question I figured it out. I decided to hit post anyway. The new call to the collaborator instantiate as member variable and new it when the test class is instantiated. 2 hours I'm not getting back.

Comment: I'd question the usefulness of that exception message.

Answer (score 4):

Return a mock object in the `whenNew()` clause would work in your case.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    whenNew(Collaborator.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock(Collaborator.class));
    myClassUnderTest.doSomething();
    verifyNew(Collaborator.class).withNoArguments();
}
```